# How to make goat simulator kid-friendly

Tags: goat-simulator

I was playing goat simulator (pc version) and one of the achievements (such as "headbutted steel bar") had the f-bomb in it??? Is it possible to turn this off? I saw in the menu where it said "turn explicit content off" but I'm 99% sure I have it off, and I don't want to check it by checking the box and learning the hard way which is which.

Is this type of language found in both modes of explicit content off and on?

Comment: You're THAT afraid to look at the written representation of a curse word? They are just words...

Comment: @user91988 Clearly you've never had to try to hide explicit content in a game from your parents - or in a more charitable interpretation of the issue, never had to try to share a gaming experience with young kids.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are definitely in explicit mode. Check the box in the menu for "full screen" and notice that a full checkbox means on. Therefore, if your "explicit content" square is full, it is on. click to turn it off.